# how to always ask password in k-9 email app android

Tags: oneplus-3, k9-mail

I have installed K9-mail in my android phone and mapped my 2 email accounts. When I open the K9-mail app, it opens without asking the email account password.

But I want to make the settings to always ask for the password before it opens an email account in that app and before its sync with the respective servers.

I have Thunderbird on my desktop and have this setting, which always prompts me for a password for the respective email accounts before it syncs (connect to email server). Could anyone help with this, please?